# Add a view in RelativeLayout from java continue

Tags: java, android, view, android-relativelayout, addition

I'm new of Android but while I am making an app , I found this problem when I add a view from java code on layout..... this is the java code and the layout XML:

```
public class second extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.labelseconda);
    EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nexus);
    InputMethodManager imm;
    imm = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(edit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    return true;    }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nexus);
    String name=item.getTitle().toString();
    if (name.equals("Save")) {
        String valor;
        valor = edit.getText().toString();
       RelativeLayout journals;
       journals = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.fragment_main);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(111111);
        tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);
       tv.setText(valor);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, button.getId());
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        // THIS THE PROBLEM
        journals.addView(tv, params);
        return true;        }
    else        {
        edit.setText("non è uguale a save");
        return true;                }    }}
```

layout xml where I want to set my new view:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="method"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is in java code, it doesn't work :  journals.addView(tv, params);

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem?  I see a few issues:

Your button defines an android:onClick property here:

```
android:onClick="method"
```

However, I don't see the implementation of this method anywhere in your activity class.  You should have something like this to handle the button touch event (you might want to use another name rather than method):

```
public void method(View v) {
   ... // do something when the user presses this button
}
```

Also, the name of the layout being loaded in onCreate does not match anything I see here:

```
R.layout.labelseconda
```

Comment: yes , but the class "second" it isn't the class where there is public void method , it isnt another class

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself badly, my problem is in the java source, when performing journalist.addview (TV, params); program by mistake but I do not understand why the parameters are wrong and perhaps other things (the layout XML that I show you called fragment_main.xml)

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException at journals.addView(tv, params);?

Comment: No, only " Unfortunately,NameApp has stopped